# Absolutely positioned element on top of link

Tags: html, css

I have some HTML that I am unable to control, but I am looking to see if I can style in such a way to achieve a certain output.  I have an a link that has a child with a link.  I have a title that is a sibling to the link, but it is absolutely positioned in the middle of the link.  When the link is hovered over, you are able to click it, however when you hover over the heading element, you can't click the link (since it is not a child of the `<a>` but rather a sibling).  Obviously if the title was a descendant of the `<a>`, I'd have no problem.

Are there any options for me to achieve my desired output?  As I said the HTML that I am styling is not able to be edited.  HTML and CSS below.

Ultimately I would like the title to be positioned above the link but still allowing the entire link to be clicked, whether hovering over the title or not.

```
<div id="" class="grid-square">
   <a href="# class="widget_sp_image-image-link">
      <img width="1920" height="1080" class="attachment-full" style="max-width: 100%;" src="...">
   </a>
   <div class="title">
      <p>TITLE</p>
   </div>
</div>


.home-grid .grid-square, .home-grid .grid-rectangle-half {
    background-color: #000;
    display: block;
    font-size: 100%;
    margin-bottom: 30px;
    overflow: hidden;
    position: relative;
}

.home-grid img {
    height: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
}

.home-grid .title {
    color: #fff;
    font-size: 4.8em;
    font-weight: 600;
    font-family: "proxima-nova-alt-condensed";
    left: 0;
    margin-bottom: 0;
    margin-top: 0;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    text-align: center;
    width: 100%;
    z-index: 1;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set the property [pointer-events](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/pointer-events) to none in the title class, to indicate that you want the mouse events to go through the title and target the link underneath.
In the following snippet you can scroll down the page and click the title or the image to go back to the top of the document.

```css
p {
    margin: 0 ;
}
.grid-square {
    position: relative ;
    width: 300px ;
    height: 800px ;
    line-height: 800px;
}
.home-grid img {
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
.home-grid .title {
    position: absolute;
    pointer-events: none;
    color: #fff;
    font-size: 4.8em;
    font-weight: 600;
    font-family: "proxima-nova-alt-condensed";
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
    vertical-align: middle;
    z-index: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="home-grid">
    <div class="grid-square">
       <a href="#top" class="widget_sp_image-image-link">
          <img class="attachment-full" src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/e/ec/Mona_Lisa%2C_by_Leonardo_da_Vinci%2C_from_C2RMF_retouched.jpg/550px-Mona_Lisa%2C_by_Leonardo_da_Vinci%2C_from_C2RMF_retouched.jpg">
       </a>
       <div class="title">
          <p>TITLE</p>
       </div>
    </div>
</div>
```